# Como atribuir o valor 0 a uma consulta retornando NULL SQL

Tags: sql, query, null

Boa tarde, estou com uma duvida a respeito de tratamento de valores em uma query.
A query abaixo ao executada retorna um valor nulo NULL como eu poderia atribuir o valor 0 em vez de NULL?

```
    select 
    master.VALPROV13 VALPROV13ACUM 
    from PFHSTPROV master (NOLOCK),PFUNC a 
    where master.CHAPA=a.CHAPA

    and
    (  ((master.CODCOLIGADA=2) 
    and  (master.CHAPA=001024)))  
    and (  master.MES = 07
    and master.ANO = 2018  )
```

Comment: Utilize a função coalesce, para o seu caso: coalesce(campo_que_pode_ser_nulo, 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em SQL Server permite a utilização da função ISNULL, função esta que valida se o output é null e cerrega o default que definires. Junto partilho a tua query para SQL Server, MySQL e Oracle.

**SQL Server**

```
 select 
    ISNULL(master.VALPROV13, 0) VALPROV13ACUM 
    from PFHSTPROV master (NOLOCK),PFUNC a 
    where master.CHAPA=a.CHAPA

    and
    (  ((master.CODCOLIGADA=2) 
    and  (master.CHAPA=001024)))  
    and (  master.MES = 07
    and master.ANO = 2018  )
```

**MySQL**

```
 select 
    IFNULL(master.VALPROV13, 0) VALPROV13ACUM 
    from PFHSTPROV master (NOLOCK),PFUNC a 
    where master.CHAPA=a.CHAPA

    and
    (  ((master.CODCOLIGADA=2) 
    and  (master.CHAPA=001024)))  
    and (  master.MES = 07
    and master.ANO = 2018  )  

Outra opção...

 select 
    COALESCE(master.VALPROV13, 0) VALPROV13ACUM 
    from PFHSTPROV master (NOLOCK),PFUNC a 
    where master.CHAPA=a.CHAPA

    and
    (  ((master.CODCOLIGADA=2) 
    and  (master.CHAPA=001024)))  
    and (  master.MES = 07
    and master.ANO = 2018  )
```

**Oracle**

```
 select 
    NVL(master.VALPROV13, 0) VALPROV13ACUM 
    from PFHSTPROV master (NOLOCK),PFUNC a 
    where master.CHAPA=a.CHAPA

    and
    (  ((master.CODCOLIGADA=2) 
    and  (master.CHAPA=001024)))  
    and (  master.MES = 07
    and master.ANO = 2018  )
```