# Inner join com avaliação antes do resultado

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um select que esta sendo feito com varios inner join. Porem uma das clausulas hora retorna vazio ou hora retorna cheio. Ja sabemos o motivo do vazio mas não sabemos como contornar a situação.

Podemos avaliar o valor caso retorne cheio segue o valor cheio caso retorne vazio devolve um valor como exemplo 99999.?

assim como segue

```
SELECT 
TLIPS.LGORT   AS     "Deposito" ,
TLIPS.CHARG   AS     "Lote" ,
TLIPS.MATNR   AS     "codProduto" ,
TLIPS.ARKTX AS       "DescProduto" ,
TLIPS.ERDAT   AS     "DataRemessa" ,
TLIPS.VBELN   AS     "NRemessa" ,
L.ERZET       AS     "HoraRemessa" ,
L.INCO1           AS "Modalidadevenda" ,
L.BTGEW           AS "QuantidadeCarga" ,
K.NAME1  AS Cliente,
CAST(COALESCE(K.KUNNR, '0') AS VARCHAR) AS cod_cliente,
CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 18 - LEN(TLIPS.MATNR)),RTRIM(TLIPS.MATNR)) as codsasf,
V2.TEXT2    AS       "PlacaCarreta",
LF.NAME1      AS     "Transportadora"

FROM LIPS AS TLIPS
INNER JOIN MARA AS M ON M.MATNR = TLIPS.MATNR 
INNER JOIN LIKP AS L ON L.VBELN = TLIPS.VBELN
INNER JOIN KNA1 AS K ON K.KUNNR = L.KUNNR
INNER JOIN VTTP AS V ON V.VBELN = TLIPS.VBELN
INNER JOIN VTTK AS V2 ON V2.TKNUM = V.TKNUM
INNER JOIN LFA1 AS LF ON LF.LIFNR = V2.TDLNR
WHERE TLIPS.VBELN = XXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi você deseja retornar o resultado mesmo que não exista a relação, neste caso você precisa pesquisar sobre others joins, exemplo: left join, right join e etc..da uma olhada aqui: http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/mysql/mysql-left-e-right-join-consultar-dados-em-duas-ou-mais-tabelas-30/

Comment: qual é o banco de dados?

Comment: primeiro, poderia contornar o valor se fosse um `left` ou `right` join, um `inner` só vai trazer valores que existirem nas duas tabelas, então me parece um pouco confuso o que escreveu, pode explicar melhor? segundo, dá pra retonar sim um valor no lugar de nulo, mas como disso, com `inner join` não deveria acontecer, a não ser que seja um campo que não está relacionado, dai é simples, mas precisa dizer qual banco de dados está usando, pois as funções usadas para tratar isso são diferentes

Comment: Para carregar um default, tenho aqui uma explicação de exemplo de outro post para vários motores de base de dados, [ISNULL()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/411662/como-atribuir-o-valor-0-a-uma-consulta-retornando-null-sql/411719#411719)